# To put all data in result set to a map in spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

```
 Multiple records will be present in result set where in for each record i have to put in map.

Result set: 

 Columns: A  B
 Data:    a1 b1
          a2 b2   
          a3 b3

Map<String String> resultMap;

resultMap.put(a1 ,b1);
resultMap.put(a2, b2);
resultMap.put(a3, b3);
```

Can any one let me know if its possible, if so  how it can be implemeted.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  Looks like a simple enough solution.

Comment: How do I map result to map. I don't see any jdbc template queries which will return map with all data in result set. queryForMap maps only one record, queryForList will return list of maps but I want only one map with all data. Using Resultsetextractor can this achieved.

Comment: Implemented using ResultSetExtractor and working as expected.